# how to filter out boolean fields in spark dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I have three columns in my data frame. In this second and third are boolean fields. I want to filter out the values which are true. i have tried this one `nn.filter(col("col3")===true).show` but it says invalid column name "true". what worng with my code? Does any help please?

my codes:

```
scala> nn.printSchema
root
 |-- ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: boolean (nullable = true)

scala> nn.show
+---+-----+-----+
| ID| col2| col3|
+---+-----+-----+
|  4| true|false|
|  5|false|false|
|  6|false|false|
|  7|false|false|
| 12|false|false|
| 13|false|false|
| 14|false|false|
| 15|false| true|
| 16|false|false|
| 17|false|false|
| 18|false|false|
| 22|false|false|
| 36|false|false|
| 37|false|false|
| 38|false|false|
| 39|false|false|
| 40|false|false|
| 41| true|false|
| 42|false|false|
+---+-----+-----+

scala> nn.filter(col("col3")===true).show
[Stage 14:>                                                         (0 + 1) / 1]19/05/26 22:44:16 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 14.0 (TID 14)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'true'.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1655)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:440)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:385)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:191)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:166)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:297)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD.compute(JDBCRDD.scala:301)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply directly filter on the boolean value. Why are you applying condition on it as `col("col3")===true`? Your column value is in boolean type and when we apply to a condition in the filter it returns value in boolean either `true` or `false`. When your column is boolean then why are you again trying the same?

```
scala> val someDf = Seq((1, true, false), (2, true, true)).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")
someDf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: int, col2: boolean ... 1 more field]
```

We have DF with the value:

```
scala> someDf.show
+----+----+-----+
|col1|col2| col3|
+----+----+-----+
|   1|true|false|
|   2|true| true|
+----+----+-----+
```

Now apply the filter:

```
scala> someDf.filter(col("col3")).show
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   2|true|true|
+----+----+----+
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
import spark.implicits._

val someDf = Seq((1, true, false), (2, true, true)).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")

someDf.show()

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

someDf.filter(col("col3")===true).show()


Original DataFrame :
+----+----+-----+
|col1|col2| col3|
+----+----+-----+
|   1|true|false|
|   2|true| true|
+----+----+-----+

Filtered Dataframe :
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   2|true|true|
+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

`===` is re-defined is `Column.scala`([reference to Spark code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.scala#L265))
The overriden method gets invoked in your case.
To avoid this,
1. Add a space after the column object like `nn.filter(col("col3") === true)`(space after `col("col3")`) or
2. Use the method suggested by @Learner like `nn.filter(col("col3"))`